# How to convert type of ImageColorFrame in Kinect for Windows SDK v1 to type of Image<> in Emgu Cv?

Tags: wpf, kinect, emgucv

I am currently working on face detection WPF Application using Emgu CV and Kinect for Windows SDK v1. I ever made same application before with Emgu CV, but using a web cam to capture the image frame. Using a web cam, it's not difficult to get the camera frame and convert it to type of Image<> in Emgu CV so that I could process it with face detection algorithm. But now, when I use color RGB camera form Kinect hardware, i can't do that. Neither implicit nor explicit conversion from type of ImageColorFrame (in Kinect for Windows SDK) to type of Image<> (in Emgu CV) are not working. How i could do that?

FYI, instead of doing a conversion, I also try to assign bytes property of type Image<> like this code below. But it's not working too. Thanks in advance.

```
using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            if (colorFrame == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            byte[] pixels = new byte[colorFrame.PixelDataLength];
            colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixels);

            nextFrame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(448, 336);
            nextFrame.Bytes = pixels;
            using (nextFrame.Bitmap = colorFrame.ToBitmap())
            {
                grayImage = new Image<Gray, byte>(448, 336);
                grayImage = nextFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
                HaarCascade faceHaarCascade = new HaarCascade("" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");

                MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = grayImage.DetectHaarCascade(
                   faceHaarCascade,
                   1.1,
                   10,
                   Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                   new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20));

                foreach (MCvAvgComp face in facesDetected[0])
                {
                    // draw rectangle in the facial image
                    nextFrame.Draw(face.rect, new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.Blue), 2);
                }
                imageVideoRGB.Source = ToBitmapSource(nextFrame);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10848309/1039947 shows how to get a Bitmap from a ColorImageFrame so you could try nextFrame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ImageToBitmap(colorFrame)); (the ImageToBitmap method is in that answer)

Answer (score 0):

To convert Microsoft.Kinect.ImageColorFrame to Emgu.CV.Image, you should try this :

```
var bitmapSource = colorImageFrame.ToBitmapSource(); // using Coding4Fun.Kinect.Wpf extension
//Get a bitmap
var currentImage = KinectHelpers.GetBitmapFromBitmapSource(ColorBitmap);
// Then get the Image
var image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(currentImage)
```

With KinectHelpers a static class :

```
public static class KinectHelpers
{
    public static Bitmap GetBitmapFromBitmapSource(BitmapSource bSource)
    {
        Bitmap bmp;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bSource));
            enc.Save(ms);
            bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
        }
        return bmp;
    }
}
```