# Convert Kinect ColorImageFrame to Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, xna, kinect, aforge

I´m using Kinect (Microsoft SDK) with XNA. I want to use GRATF for marker-recognition

How to convert the data of a Kinect `ColorImageFrame` to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` or `AForge.Imaging.UnmanagedImage` that I can process them with GRATF?

```
void kinectSensor_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    ColorImageFrame frame = e.OpenColorImageFrame();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[frame.PixelDataLength];
    frame.CopyPixelData(buffer);

    // how to convert the data in buffer to a bitmap?

    var glyphs = recognizer.FindGlyphs(bitmap);

    ...
}
```

Comment: look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730842/Kinect-for-Windows-version-Color-depth-and-infra
(i know this is old, but for whoever seeing it now)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the answer [*in this article*](http://www.i-programmer.info/ebooks/practical-windows-kinect-in-c/3725-getting-started-with-windows-kinect-sdk-10.html?start=2).
To summarize it, this method should do the trick:

```
Bitmap ImageToBitmap(ColorImageFrame img)
{
     byte[] pixeldata = new byte[img.PixelDataLength];
     img.CopyPixelDataTo(pixeldata);
     Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
     BitmapData bmapdata = bmap.LockBits(
         new Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height),
         ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, 
         bmap.PixelFormat);
     IntPtr ptr = bmapdata.Scan0;
     Marshal.Copy(pixeldata, 0, ptr, img.PixelDataLength);
     bmap.UnlockBits(bmapdata);
     return bmap;
 }
```

Comment: why is this giving A=255 all the time?

Comment: @MdSifatulIslam, the `PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb` does not use alpha. Use `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` to get an alpha value.  You will have to pad the `pixeldata` array with an alpha value before the `Marshal.Copy` or the data will be the wrong size.