# Capturing Kinect Depth Image to a png file

Tags: c#, image, kinect

I am trying to save a kinect depth sensor image to a png file. I tried to take this with my RGB camera and it didn't have any problems. Is there something that I missed out on?
P.S. I am using Kinect ToolKit's functions for both rgb and depth image display.

```
WriteableBitmap depthBitmap;
DepthStreamManager dsm;
dsm = new DepthStreamManager();
kinect.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
kinect.DepthFrameReady += kinect_DepthFrameReady;
depthBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(kinect.DepthStream.FrameWidth,this.kinect.DepthStream.FrameHeight, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Gray16, null);
private string TakeImage(int x)
    {
        if (x == 0)
        {
            BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(this.depthBitmap));
            string myPhotos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(myPhotos, "Image 1.png");
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(fs);
                }


            }
            catch (IOException details)
            {
                Console.Write(details.ToString());

            }
            if (path == null)
                return "Image was not taken.";
            else
                return path;
        }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to my own problem:

Using Kinect's ToolKit, they actually supplied a writable bitmap function that allows me to grab the ColorStreamManager or DepthStreamManager's WritableBitmap out. My error previously was that since I wasn't using Kinect's innate display methods, the writeablebitmap will definitely be empty. This is my fixed codes.

```
WriteableBitmap wmp;
            wmp = cis.Bitmap;
            BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wmp));
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),"Image 1.png");
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(fs);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ioe.ToString());
            }
            return path;
```

Comment: What is cis in `wmp=cis.Bitmap; `
is it any class object from some library...?
if so which library? and also Reference in solutioExplorer..?
Sorry for such a basic question but I'm new to this field..

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [Coding4Fun Kinect toolkit](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Coding4Fun-Kinect-Toolkit), I believe you can use ImageFrame objects. You can convert an [ImageFrame object to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848190/convert-kinect-colorframe-to-bitmap) and from there you should be able to [save it as a PNG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) with no problems.

Bit of a long-winded route to the solution but I'm not currently using the machine which has my Kinect stuff on it.

Edit: If you're using WinForms, you can simply use the Coding4Fun toolkit method ImageFrame.ToBitmap() and then save as PNG from there.

The code should look something like this:

```
private void saveAsPNG(ImageFrame myImageFrame, string path)
{
   Bitmap bmp = myImageFrame.ToBitmap();

   bmp.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

   bmp.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I doesn't seem to work for wpf. I tried out Coding4Fun's stuff before but I moved away because it's really not detailed enough for some stuff.

Comment: You're right, the Coding4Fun library is good for only basic things. I used WPF in a Kinect project recently and it can be a right pain for some simple things. Just off the top of my head I don't think I can expand my answer to help you any more. The best of luck.

Comment: Did you use the solution I suggested, or another? If you used another solution, I'd love to see it and I'm sure others would too. **Edit: Apologies, I didn't see you'd already posted it. Thanks :)**

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the *WriteableBitmap*. Just the *encoder* with a *BitmapSource* that holds the *pixeldata*.

```
using Microsoft.Kinect;
using System.Windows.Media; // WindowsBase
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; //PresentationCore
```

...

```
static void sensor_DepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {

        DepthImageFrame DIF = e.OpenDepthImageFrame();
        if (DIF == null){return;}            

        short[] pixels = new short[DIF.PixelDataLength];
        DIF.CopyPixelDataTo(pixels);

        if (check == 0)
        {
            int stride = DIF.Width * DIF.BytesPerPixel;
            BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(BitmapSource.Create(
                DIF.Width, DIF.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray16, null, pixels, stride)));

            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "kimage.png");

            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(fs);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ioe.ToString());
            }
            check = 1;
        }}
```

ENVIRONMENT:

- Visual Studio 2012 express
- Microsoft.Kinect Library 1.7.0.0
- *Encoder* needs the assembly System.Xaml