# Bitmap to avi exception

Tags: kinect, avi, kinect-sdk, vfw

I am using the [Simple C# Wrapper for the AviFile Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library), and the code snippet I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848190/convert-kinect-colorframe-to-bitmap) in order create an avi file from Kinect's color frames.

And I get this exception: "Exception in AVIFileOpen: -2147205009"

```
        aviManager = new AviManager(@"C:\temp\temp.avi", false);
        aviStream = aviManager.AddVideoStream(false, 30, _firstBitmap);
```

Where the "_firstBitmap" is generated with the [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848190/convert-kinect-colorframe-to-bitmap) mentioned above

```
Bitmap ImageToBitmap(ColorImageFrame Image)
{
     byte[] pixeldata = new byte[Image.PixelDataLength];
     Image.CopyPixelDataTo(pixeldata);
     Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(Image.Width, Image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
     BitmapData bmapdata = bmap.LockBits(
         new Rectangle(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height),
         ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, 
         bmap.PixelFormat);
     IntPtr ptr = bmapdata.Scan0;
     Marshal.Copy(pixeldata, 0, ptr, Image.PixelDataLength);
     bmap.UnlockBits(bmapdata);
     return bmap;
 }
```

And the Color frame image is provided from the Kinect SDK's ColorFrameReady delegate

```
private void SensorColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
    {
        if (colorFrame != null)
        {
            // Copy the pixel data from the image to a temporary array
            colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.colorPixels);

            // Write the pixel data into our bitmap
            this.colorBitmap.WritePixels(
                new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight),
                this.colorPixels,
                this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth * sizeof(int),
                0);
            AviManager aviManager = new AviManager(@"C:\temp\temp.avi", false);
            VideoStream aviStream = aviManager.AddVideoStream(false, 30, bmp);

            Bitmap bitmap = ImageToBitmap(colorFrame);
            aviStream.AddFrame(bitmap);
            bitmap.Dispose();
            aviManager.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: What is `_firstBitmap` defined as?  Please include the code that initializes and declares all the variables.

Comment: _firstBitmap is System.Drawing.Bitmap, and it resulted from the ImageToBitmap function mentioned in the link above.

Comment: The error is `AVIERR_FILEOPEN`, you will need to look at `AVIFileOpen` arguments to possibly see why your are hitting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) framework provides several functions that allow you to easily write AVI, or other, video files.  It also provides [direct support](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/ec99e402-afc6-f187-4269-8e640ef5a26f.htm) for the Kinect, allowing you to get access to the video camera.

However, per information on the website, it requires `libfreenect`.  I am unaware if `libfreenect` and the office Kinect SDK can live in harmony with each other in the same application.

The [AVIWriter class](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/avi_files.html) is pretty straight forward and would not necessarily require you to use AForge.NET's Kinect access.  You could just as easily get the latest color frame from the official Kinect SDK, convert it to a `Bitmap` and output it.

Comment: What is the difference between Aforge AVI writer and the "Simple C# Wrapper for the AviFile Library" if they both wrap the same obselete windows AVI library ?