# kinect - I can poll for frame data, but the events are not working

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I was trying a basic "hello world" app for a first kinect project, to stream the video data to the stream.  The code is here: https://github.com/fschwiet/HelloKinect/blob/8803b6b959ee6dba5f9284b9e732fb11a897dea4/HelloKinect/ShowCameraCommand.cs

What I find is that I can poll for frame data in a loop, but I am not receiving the frame-ready events.  The sourcecode is below.  When UsePolling is true, frame data is sent to the form.  When UsePolling is false, there is console output "Hit return to exit." indicating everything has run, but no events are ever received.

I have a feeling this has to do with windows message pumps, that I need to wait in an alertable state and/or pump a message queue.  I haven't been able to make it work though, anyone have any hints?

```
public class ShowCameraCommand : ConsoleCommand
{
    static private Form EchoForm;
    private bool UsePolling;

    public ShowCameraCommand()
    {
        this.IsCommand("show-camera");
        this.HasOption("p", "Use polling to check frame data", v => UsePolling = true);
    }

    public override int Run(string[] remainingArguments)
    {
        var sensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors.Where(s => s.Status == KinectStatus.Connected).FirstOrDefault();

        if (sensor == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Kinect was not detected");
            Console.WriteLine();
            return -1;
        }

        EchoForm = new Form();

        EchoForm.Width = 640;
        EchoForm.Height = 480;

        EchoForm.Show();

        sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RawYuvResolution640x480Fps15);

        if (!UsePolling)
        {
            sensor.ColorFrameReady += sensor_ColorFrameReady;
        }

        sensor.Start();

        if (UsePolling)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Use any key to exit.");
            while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                using (var frame = sensor.ColorStream.OpenNextFrame(10 * 1000))
                {
                    HandleFrame(frame);
                }

                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hit return to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void sensor_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Frame received");
        using (ColorImageFrame frame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            HandleFrame(frame);
        }
    }

    private void HandleFrame(ColorImageFrame frame)
    {
        var bitmap = ImageToBitmap(frame);

        using (var g = EchoForm.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Frame drawn");
        }
    }

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848190/convert-kinect-colorframe-to-bitmap
    Bitmap ImageToBitmap(ColorImageFrame Image)
    {
        byte[] pixeldata = new byte[Image.PixelDataLength];
        Image.CopyPixelDataTo(pixeldata);
        Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(Image.Width, Image.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        BitmapData bmapdata = bmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height),
            ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
            bmap.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr ptr = bmapdata.Scan0;
        Marshal.Copy(pixeldata, 0, ptr, Image.PixelDataLength);
        bmap.UnlockBits(bmapdata);
        return bmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, figured it out.  I needed to call Application.Run() to start pumping events.